# DYNAMIC UNPIVOTING the Table

Tags: mysql

**Raw data_ Table**

```
dt1    transaction_1   dt2   transaction_2   dt3   transaction_3....dt80  tra_80
may01    22            jun01    56           Aug09   73             jun09  22
sep02    49            feb12    53           dec23   80             Aug12  21
```

Now the output should be

```
dt      transaction        type
may01    22             transaction_1  
sep02    49             transaction_1   
jun01    56             transaction_2
feb12    53              transaction_2
Aug09    73              transaction_3
dec23    80              transaction_3
...     ..             ...
jun09    22              transaction_80
Aug12    21              transaction_80
```

Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you explain in more detail what you need to do?

Comment: need to append every two variable by one by one so far I did                                   SELECT dt1    as datepart, transaction_1   as transaction, 'transaction_1  ' 
FROM samp1

UNION all

SELECT dt2, transaction_2   , 'transaction_2   ' 
FROM samp1 ;

Comment: like this i have 80+ variable so, is there any dynamic way to code

Comment: What an horrendous design, I needed to comment that. You can do it as this answer http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47954 . This is the Idea since it do what you want in reverse. Changing the code a bit you will get it.